# Regex String zero or more

Tags: php, regex, string

I have follow Regex:

```
(.*?)( EUR)\1*
```

and on String `2 mm; EUR` it matches `2mm;` and `EUR` 
but the String `2 mm;` matches nothing!?

But why ? I thought the `*` meant zero or more times?
Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Because there's no `EUR` in that string

Comment: But i have the "*" behind? That say 0 or more matches?

Comment: Quantifiers apply to the token it precedes. In this case the dot `.`. If you want to make `EUR` optional then drop another question mark after it `( EUR)?`. `?` : zero or one time.

Comment: Why do you have `\1*`. Can `EUR` be there multiple times?

Comment: Yes " EUR" can be there multiple times...

Comment: ok then add some example inputs and their expected matches to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been a better approach to tell what result you want.

If you want a Regex to match "2 mm; EUR" or "2 mm;", it implies that you want to match a string starting with some kind of number (might be a millimiter length? something like that), ending with a ";" and eventually followed by the string " EUR".

If it is what you want, your regex should have a ";" inside and mark EUR with a "?" (0 or 1)

```
([\n]+ .*?);( EUR)?
```

Comment: Thank you!
The result i wish is:
if found " EUR" than return everything before
if not then result all

The "mm" and ";" ar not sure... only sure is the " EUR" but also it also can like "4mm 7,50 EUR EUR EUR"

Answer (score 1):

The following *regex* will match both cases, `2 mm; EUR` as well as `2 mm;`

```
(.*?;\s)(EUR)|(.*;)
```

[Example](https://www.regex101.com/r/yN6aR2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right `*` means 'zero or more times'. What you don't seem to understand is `\1`. It means 'the content captured by the first caturing group.

Your regular expression `(.*?)( EUR)\1*` means therefore:

any string, followed by the four letters `EUR` (with a space), followed by zero or more times the start of the string.

If the string is `2 mm; EUR2 mm;2 mm;`, `(.*?)` will match `2 mm;`, `( EUR)` will match `EUR`, and `\1*` will match `2 mm;2 mm;`.

Now that you understand your error, you will find more easily the correct expression. Just remove `\1`.

```
(.*?)( EUR)*
```

will match anything, followed be zero or more times `EUR`.

```
^(.*?)( EUR.*)?$
```

will match anything before ' EUR',  or the whole string if it is missing. Notice that we added the start and end marks to make sure the whole string is captured when there is no EUR.

Comment: Thats not exactly what i search for...
i will get everything before ( EUR) and if that not exist then return everything...

Comment: Two qestion to make sure that this is the correct regex : If EUR is in the middle of the string, is it correct to neglect everything that follows ? Is it guaranteed that there is a space before EUR.